# Debug a program run from External tool in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I have a java application that runs from a batch file.
I have used an external tool for this.

However, I am not able to debug this application through eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You have to launch your java application with [remote debug options](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-javadebug/index.html).

Then you can create a remote debug configuration in your Eclipse to attach that jvm process.